# Equivalent of Matlab's PCA in Python sklearn

Tags: python, matlab, scikit-learn

I'm a Matlab user and I'm learning Python with the sklearn library. I want to translate this Matlab code

```matlab
[coeff,score] = pca(X)
```

For `coeff` I have tried this in Python:

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np
pca = PCA()
pca.fit(X)
coeff = print(np.transpose(pca.components_))
```

I don't know whether or not it's right; for `score` I have no idea.

Could anyone enlight me about correctness of `coeff` and feasibility of `score`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PCA` score in sklearn is different from matlab.

In sklearn,  `pca.score()` or `pca.score_samples()` gives the log-likelihood of samples whereas matlab gives the principal components.

From [sklearn Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.score_samples):

> Return the log-likelihood of each sample.
>
> **Parameters:**
>   **X :** array, shape(n_samples, n_features) 
>         The data.
>   **Returns:**
>   **ll :** array, shape (n_samples,) 
>         Log-likelihood of each sample under the current model

From [matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html#btjpztu-1):

> [coeff,score,latent] = pca(___) also returns the principal component
>   scores in score and the principal component variances in latent. You
>   can use any of the input arguments in the previous syntaxes.
>
> **Principal component scores are the representations of X in the**
>   **principal component space**. Rows of score correspond to observations,
>   and columns correspond to components.
>
> The principal component variances are the eigenvalues of the
>   covariance matrix of X.

Now, the equivalent of `matlab` `score` in pca is [`fit_transform()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit_transform) or [`transform()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.transform) :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
>>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
>>> pca = PCA(n_components=2)
>>> matlab_equi_score = pca.fit_transform(X)
```

Answer (score 2):

The sklearn PCA has a `score` method as described in the documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

Try: `pca.score(X)` or `pca.score_samples(X)` depending whether you wish a score for each sample (the latter) or a single score for all samples (the former)